# How to communicate between two seprate docker containers via “localhost"?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

Hello I am having issues with communicating between two sperate docker containers.
One is a flask app, which is running on port 5000 (port exposed to local, FROM localhost i can access this flask app via http://localhost:5000/api) but there is another react app docker container running on port 3000 the problem is i need to hit the flask api, whenever i try to make request to http://localhost:5000/api from inside of container it is not letting me to do that.
any help ?

Here is the docker-compose file of react app
version: '3'

```
services:

  react-cms:
      tty: true 
      build: .
      ports: 
          - "8080:3000"
```

Here is the compose file of Flask app

```
version: '3'

services:

  video_service:

    build: video_service/.
    
    ports: 
        - 5001:5000
```

Comment: Don't you need both ports exposed on each container?

Comment: can you show your docker-compose file?

Comment: @ThatGuyKev i have updated the question with compose files.

Comment: @AleksanderBobiński yes i have exposed the ports.

Comment: as each containers will have thier own namespace , localhost on Host Machine will be different to the localhost inside the container ,. Try http://<hostIP>:5000/

Comment: @confusedgenius is there any better way i do not want to change host ip every time i deploy on different servers

Comment: @R.singh awesome! I'll post the answer

Comment: Basically if you are able to reach other container with its from another container you requirement will be met . [check this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-ping-docker-container-from-another-container-by-name)

Comment: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes the overall network environment you have available and how to connect between containers.  `localhost` is "this container", not any other container or the host system.

Answer (score 1):

If you add 'video_service' dependency to the docker-compose where you have 'react-cms' that would mean, the video_service container is no longer able to maintain it's own life span (if you will) because the docker-compose down for react-cms will also bring down the video_service container.

What I would do, run viedoe_service and react-cms as they are (that means, different docker-compose), but keep both the containers on the same network. So that, react-cms can make api calls to viedoe_service. Please visit the docker documentation page https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

But here is the idea what I would do,

Step 1: Add network to viedoe_service level like this,

```
networks: 
      - my_react_video_service_network
```

Then declare and define networks on services level like this,

```
networks: 
  my_react_video_service_network: 
    name: my_react_video_service_network
```

Step 2: Connect to my_react_video_service_network from react-cms. Add to services level like this,

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my_react_video_service_network
```

So, now you have the react-service container running on the same network as video_service container, therefor, react-service should able to consume video_service api.

Answer (score 0):

if you want react-cms to access video-service you need to include it in your docker-compose file.

```
  react-cms:
    depends_on: 
      - video_service
    environment: 
      - VIDEO_SERVICE_URI=video_service/api
```

then you can access the service through the environment variable

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, will try this, however, I have confusion the video_service is created and running in a separate container if I did what you said wouldn't that cause any issue?

Comment: yeah it should run with no issues, however, you may face other related issues. From what I see you're implemting microservices-like system, this method always works for me. Anyway, let me know here in the comments if it didn't work.

Comment: the thing is you have suggested " build: video_service/." in the video service tag, I do not have access to that directory, that service is already build and running in a separate container. Any suggestions?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake, I just added few lines to your code, I'll edit that

Comment: are you saying that you have more than one 'docker-compose' file?

Comment: sure, let's do it